# What are steps to make a program which will protect my tutorial video from being copy?

Tags: java, c#

I made some video tutorials which customer can buy them from my website and i will send videos on DVDs to them .
But they will copy my video and give to each other without any more paying!
I want to write a program which keep my videos safe just in these type of problem ( I know they can capture screen !) .So what are the steps? 
(as a detail i can write code in C# , JAVA for windows side and PHP for server side)
(because DVDs are note long lifetime i prefer to install my videos inside a program on their computer)
( I already can write Android application for this problem because android has some safe directory to put my data which user has not access to that directory .what i want is same thing on windows)

I expect the way which install my program on a single computer which user must active his/her program with serial key (which check through internet api).
Then I expect my video won't show regularly like *.mp4 to user ! ( should i put my video to a database ?!)( or encrypt them ? )

Comment: Really, you can't.  If somebody wants to copy your video, they'll find a way, no matter what you do.

Comment: Easy, just use burn your content with AACS.  It will drive output working in conjunction with HDCP.

Comment: Tnx MickyD . Is AACS a way to burn data on DVD ? if it is i don't want to do that on DVD side . if it is rule in your country which tell people to do not copy data -> we have some similar rule but they don't care they will copy!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Access_Content_System.

Comment: Thank you MickyD .I'm gonna search for it .sounds interesting .

Answer (score 0):

make your website where people can subscribe and only watch your tutorials videos whenever they want but not download them, like lynda.com etc. Its not easy but if you want to protect your videos, you have to do it.

Comment: Not a good choose .it has a lot extra cost for me and them ! ( data are about 12 gigabyte )